# Pull request communication strategy needed

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment, pull-request, git-flow

Doing trunk based development to **achieve continuous deployment**. And this is our branching strategy.

> **master** > whats live in production
>
> **release** > test passed and release point created by CI server
>
> **dev** > daily merges from the development team.

If we consider doing the pull request from release to master stage. 
What are the pros and cons to that approach? How can we communicate this with the development team where they want to do PR at dev branch?

[image]

Comment: from the image you are already doing that, what exactly you mean?

Comment: Seems like a pretty sound strategy. So Master is actually the branch that gets deployed, and you use the Release branch as milestones for particular versions? I guess one drawback might be if you need to roll back, and it's not as simple as just checking out the release tag and re-deploying it - but if you're doing releases small and often, fixing forward is a legit option.

Comment: The concern is the development team wants to do the PR at dev branch which is an automation killer. How should I approach the problem?

Comment: @RıfatErdemSahin Should they do pr from develop to release or what do you want to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I don't really have an answer, but think the context of the question is worth further discussion.*

If you're doing Continuous Deployment, then I'm not sure of the purpose of the Release branch.   It seems to be duplicating the purpose of either:

- 'master': code being deployed/released
- 'develop' integrated feature
  branches, but not ready release

Or, are you using it to group milestones or planned major releases (i.e. *Release/1.0*, *Release/2.0*), like a mini-master branch.
I would not consider this Continuous Delivery (deployment, maybe), but it is certainly a valid pattern if your project requires staged releases rather than Continuous Delivery.

It's also important to also consider your CI setup and how it integrates with your branches. It isn't source code that is deployed to Production, but the build artifacts from  your CI system.  Thinking about this might simplify your branching model.
If you want to rollback, you don't want to rebuild the application from source, you want to re-deploy the pre-built artifacts of the previous version.  Likewise, if you have a build that has passed all your tests and is ready to ship - hopefully is already running on your pre-production environments - you don't want to merge it to a different branch, rebuild it and then deploy the new build - you use the build that was tested.

The next consideration is that every additional branch adds time & complexity for the developers.   Merging, pull requests, waiting for CI to run, etc. are not free so reducing the complexity of the branching strategy to the minimum you require is a good goal.

To answer your question about where to PR to/from, do you consider "Develop" as the mainline and attempt to keep it stable and working at all times?
If so, then the PRs from feature-to-develop are the key integration. Develop is then built, tested, and deployed to your test environments.
Branching from develop at that point (i.e. to create a Release branch) is then known to be good. 
Promoting that artifact from your test environment to production, without re-building, might remove the need for one of your branches.

Comment: If you're doing Continuous Deployment, then I'm not sure of the purpose of the Release branch. It seems to be duplicating the purpose of either:

We want to lock the projects at some state for business to check what has been done. Thinking about the release points are as quality checked code.